# accessing Static final instance variable into static method error

Tags: java, static

I came across this particular behavior while working but I am not really sure what is the issue here. As per me **Static** keyWord has some feature as

**1. Belongs to class rather than object.**

**2. Static method can access static instance variable of the class.**

But can some one please expain the particular behavior:

```
      public static final int x=12;
      public static  void go(final int x){
          System.out.println(this.x);
      }
```

while writing this particular line I am getting **complile** time error at printing statement **"this.x"** in Eclipse as ***"can't use this in static conetext"***.

Can some one explain what is missing in my understanding??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't specify that you want the class level `x` with `this`. You need the class name. Like,

```
class Example {
  public static final int x=12;
  public static  void go(final int x){
    System.out.println(Example.x);
  }
}
```

You could also use a different variable name for the method parameter.

```
public static final int x=12;
public static void go(final int y){
  System.out.println(x);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

"**this**" refer to current object and not to class.

It should be like

```
public static final int x=12;
      public static  void go(final int x){
          System.out.println(ClassName.x);
      }
```